# Error when trying to use np.loadtxt()

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I've seen several answers to this issue, mostly suggesting I replace np.loadtxt with np.genfromtxt()....but that produces a different issue.

The line in question is:

```
imported_array = np.loadtxt(fname, delimiter='\t', skiprows = 1)
```

The file itself claims to be a .xls but I've discovered that it's really a tab-delimited text file. This code usually works on files generated by this system. The data looks like

```
Time    Flow Rate    Pressure  
0.002   273.4474545 3.542497271
```

and so on. The error I'm getting is

```
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

And the thing it claims is a string is a weird character...it's possibly a capital gamma. Which I cannot find in the data file. Everything below the first row is a number, and definitely not a capital gamma. I tried searching the files for the special characters that look like it, to no avail.

When I try it with np.genfromtxt:

```
imported_array = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter='\t', skiprows = 1)   

 raise ValueError(errmsg)
 ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #3 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #7 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
Line #9 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #59 (got 14 columns instead of 1)
Line #61 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #70 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #71 (got 4 columns instead of 1)
```

Meanwhile, on previous sets of data generated from the same system, I have either not had this problem or had one out of maybe 20 that had this issue.

Comment: Apparently the number of tabs per line is not fixed ... on line 59 there are 13 tabs according to the error readings. Apart from that you should use `skip_header=1` instead of `skip_rows=1`

Comment: This data is 66 columns wide and about 3700 rows long. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that from [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) that my problem was most likely related to the fact that despite the files being NAMED .xls, they weren't .xls files. I was specifying the delimiter, which was tabs. I'm not sure why it worked sometimes and not others. However, when I altered the line to:

```
    imported_array = np.genfromtxt(fname, skiprows = 1, dtype = float)
```

(removing the delimiter specification), it worked.

It also worked as np.loadtxt with the same parameters. It's really weird to me that specifying the delimiter was messing me up.